# Triangle of numbers sum

Tags: combinatorics

What is the total of all these numbers?

```
                  1 
                 1 2
                1 2 3
               1 2 3 4
              1 2 3 4 5
             . . . . . .
            1 2 ........N
```

The answer should be a single binomial coefficient. It looks pretty easy, but I cannot come to a solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The sum of the $k$-th row is $\sum_{h=1}^k h=\frac{k(k+1)}{2}$.

Recalling that $\sum\limits_{k=1}^n k^2=\frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6}$, we have that the sum of the numbers in the triangle is $$\sum_{k=1}^n \left(\frac{k^2}{2}+\frac{k}{2}\right)=\frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{12}+\frac{n(n+1)}{4}=\\=\frac{n(n+1)(2n+4)}{12}=\frac{n(n+1)(n+2)}{6}=\\=\binom{n+2}{3}$$

Comment: Thanks, I really like this approach. I had forgotten about the sum of squares formula.

Answer (score 0):

The total of the $1$'s is $N$. The total of the $2$'s is $2(N-1)$, the toal of the $3$'s is $3(N-2)$,..., the total of the $N$'s is $N(N-(N-1))=N$.

Throwing this into a sum we find:

$$\sum_{i=1}^N i \cdot (N-(i-1)) = \sum_{i=1}^N i \cdot N - \sum_{i=1}^N i^2 + \sum_{i=1}^N i$$
$$= N \frac{N(N+1)}{2} - \frac{N(N+1)(2N+1)}{6} + \frac{N(N+1)}{2}$$
$$= \frac{N(N+1)^2}{2} - \frac{N(N+1)(2N+1)}{6}.$$

We can factor this into $$N(N+1) \left( \frac{(N+1)}{2} - \frac{(2N+1)}{6} \right)$$
$$=N(N+1) \left( \frac{N+2}{6} \right) = \frac{N(N+1)(N+2)}{6} = \frac{(N+2)!}{(N-1)!3!} = { N+2 \choose 3 }$$

Comment: Thanks! The answer is correct, but I was looking for a binomial coefficient. Anyway, the rest is a matter of computation.

Comment: @CombStudent23, not to quip, but I did provide the binomial coefficient at the end of my post. I tend to edit a bit right after I post, so you might have missed it.

Comment: Yes sorry, I saw it before the edition.

Comment: I wonder if there is a direct way of recognizing this as $N+2 \choose 3$, rather than going through sums...